# how to create record via POST (using POSTMAN)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm brand new to rails and did the getting started of guides.rubyonrails.org and now i'm facing a problem with creating a record.

I try to send this json:
    {
    "title": "someTitle",
    "text": "someText"
    }

to 
    http://www.justatest/articles.json

My Model only has this title and text field as attribute defined.

Route is setup too. And my controller create method looks like that:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

   if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

I've set POSTMAN to method POST when doing the request but i get this error message:
ActionController::ParameterMissing
      in ArticlesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the json need to be like:

```
{ article: { title: "someTitle", text: "someText" } }
```

The method `article_params` tries to find a key named `article`, and your json don't have it.

Comment: even with that i get: "param is missing or the value is empty: article"

if i do: http://localhost:3000/articles.json?article[title]=someTitle&article[text]=someText via POST it works though. But i hoped I can create a record via POST and json format

Comment: ok i guess rails just expects POST fields, it seems it expects url encoded form vals. your answer pointet me into the right direction so thx MurifoX

Comment: ah ok nevermind, now i've got it working. the content-type=application/json needs to be set AND it must be real JSON format so it must look like this:
{ "article": { "title": "someTitle", "text": "someText" } }

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, you must set the ContentType headers to be 'application/json', and the relevant fields for creating your record.

Upon receiving this request, Rails recognizes the headers as JSON, and then parses the JSON into the 'params' we all know and love.

Here is a [link some of the source in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb#L43) that deals with this.

Comment: oh wow thanks for this detailed link to the internas of rails :) now its crystal clear to me :)